# Looping elements in two lists into Excel spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, list

I want to write two lists into an Excel spreadsheet.

It’s basically looping the elements in the 2 lists.

```
name_list = ["Mary", "Jack", "David"]
project_list = ["Project X", "Project Y", "Project K"]
```

The result shall look like:

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='cp1252', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

name_list = ["Mary", "Jack", "David"]
project_list = ["Project X", "Project Y", "Project K"]

for num, name in enumerate(name_list):
    for num1, project in enumerate(project_list):
        sheet.write(num, 0, name)
        sheet.write(num1, 1, project)

book.save("C:\\output.xls")
```

Obviously it's far from what I expected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
num1 = 0
for  name in name_list:
    for project in project_list:
        sheet.write(num1, 0, name)
        sheet.write(num1, 1, project)
        num1 += 1
```

Comment: I think instead of `num1` it could be better to use `row` as the variable name

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal, thank you. just now I had a chance to catch yours. it works fine but just leaving the first row blank.

Comment: @MarkK as per `excel` the row number starts at 1 so I started at 1 - it's the same answer, no need for duplicates. :)